# django acces the setting given in --settings argument on runserver in program

Tags: python, django

I often run my django development server with different settings given as parameter as shown in the example below:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=my_project.settings.andi
```

But sometimes it is `.andi` and sometimes something `.other`.

How to make **universal** import statement, which will be able to access this settings always?

---

TO make clear how it works, and answer to the suggestion Santosh Ghimire:
I have `base.py` which I import in any other (e.g andi) with statetment `from .base import *`
The way to access the things, which are extra added in `andi` is the one proposed by bruno desthuilliers, i.e with:
`from django.conf import settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "how do my django apps modules know which settings to import", the answer is simply to replace any `import settings` with `from django.conf import settings`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you separate these different settings in separate files like `settings_local.py` and `settings_remote.py` and import each one on necessity in the main `settings.py` file that holds all the common settings.

This way you won't have to give optional parameters in the runserver command.